# Handle corrupt images from JSON in android

Tags: android, json

Iam getting some image URLs in my JSON which I parse and show in my image view. So if the Url is null, I show a default image. But in some cases the Urls are specified but the images are corrupted. In this case nothing displays in the ImageView only a white space shows. Is there any way I can handle this scenario.

Any help will be useful.

Comment: if the image is corrupted, then the image size is zero ?

Comment: Catch any exceptions in the HTTP download of the image or the creation of the bitmap from the stream and display the default image instead.

Comment: @Signare. I get a Status code ok. But an empty response

Comment: every time you get status as ok?. @user3034944

Comment: @Signare yes. the satus is ok all the time. But if I click on the image url and open in the browser, it says the image blob not found

Comment: download the image on device and check its size ? @user3034944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use picasso bro

A very easy image handling library for android

Picasso supports both download and error placeholders as optional features.

```
 Picasso.with(context)
     .load(url)
   .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
   .into(imageView);
```

http://square.github.io/picasso/

and yes,its that easy

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImageLoader` to check this case. Example:

```
private ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
private ImageView Iv;
private String URL =null;
private DisplayImageOptions mDio;

URL = "URL you get from your JSON";

    if (URL != null) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(URL, Iv, mDio, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                         // check corrupt images on here 
                            view.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv_fail)
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            if (loadedImage != null) {
                              view.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current,
                                                     int total) {
                        }
                    });
        } else Iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.iv_default);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do it easily is to use proper lib - Use [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or something else. Advantages is that this libs are well maintained and is stable. Your empty image will be treated as an error and default will be shown